# What happens if the consumer of a virtual topic goes down?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ JMS-to-JMS bridge, in which messages from a remote broker are forwarded to a virtual topic on a local ActiveMQ cluster.  The consumers of the virtual topic communicate with the ActiveMQ cluster via the failover protocol.  What happens if the entire cluster has a catastrophic meltdown?  Will messages that were produced during the downtime appear on the virtual topic when the cluster is online again, like with durable subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if the entire ActiveMQ cluster goes down, then messages produced during that downtime will be lost, unless the consumers are configured to be durable.  In other words, virtual topics don't have durability in and of themselves.